# Load pdf ,word files to PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I want to extract data from pdf and word in Pig hadoop.
I am trying to load files using builtin storage functions but its in different encoding.So I can't process it.

How can i load pdf into pig.

===========this is what i did=============

```
REGISTER '/home/itelligence/Desktop/POC/UTF8.jar'; 

A = LOAD'/home/itelligence/Desktop/POC/namecheap-order-17742559.pdf' using TextLoader() AS (line:chararray); (also tried using bytearray)when pig send argument of bytearray to udf does it gets converted to string/chararray

B = FOREACH A GENERATE udfansitoUTF8.AnsiToUTF8(line);
```

there is no error the op is something like this

([B@38bcf402)

([B@7d37cc67)

([B@5a4cbe6a)

the udf is

```
            try
            {
                String str = (String) input.get(0);
                ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));


                 byte[] convertedBytes = StringUtils.getBytesUsAscii(str);
                 return convertedBytes.toString();

            }
            catch ( Exception uee )
            {
                return "error ";
            }

    }
```

}

Comment: Which precise builtin storage function are you using? What is the error message?

Comment: have updated the q please ans .............have tried using pigstorage() also ...when we send a bytearray as a argument to udf does it get converted to string or chararray .........

Comment: Sorry, can't help, I was just reviewing the question which lacked information. Hopefully hadoop peeps can answer this.